# Use the second isomorphism theorem to show that (∩)/(∩) is Abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that ,, are subgroups of ,  is a normal subgroup of . Assume / is Abelian. Use the second isomorphism theorem to show that (∩)/(∩) is Abelian.

I can show (∩)M is a subgroup of . However, I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: [Here's what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blkhm.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second isomorphism theorem says that, given a subgroup $S$ of a group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ of $G,$ then

- $SN$ is a subgroup of $G,$
- $S\cap N$ is a normal subgroup of $S,$ and
- $(SN)/N\cong S/(S\cap N).$

Here, though, our (sub)groups are named differently. Instead of $S,$ we're considering $N\cap H;$ instead of $N,$ $M;$ instead of $G,$ $N.$

You're right that $(N\cap H)M$ is a subgroup of $N$ (the first point above), but we also should observe that $$(N\cap H)\cap M=(N\cap M)\cap H=M\cap H$$ is a normal subgroup of $N$ (the second point above, using the fact that $M\subseteq N$) and that $(N\cap H)M/M\cong (N\cap H)/(M\cap H)$ (the third point above).

I would then show that $(N\cap H)M/M$ is a subgroup of the abelian group $N/M,$ so is abelian, itself, whence the proof is complete.